# PHP, loop in a loop with dynamic variables and array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, dynamic

I just finished a script, but I know, I can make it cleaner. I kind of need help for this.

Here is the final loop of my code :

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nba ; $i++){
    fputcsv($fp, array($r{0}[$i],$r{1}[$i],$r{2}[$i],$r{3}[$i],$r{4}[$i],$r{5}[$i],$r{6}[$i],$r{7}[$i],$r{8}[$i],$r{9}[$i],$r{10}[$i],$r{11}[$i],$r{12}[$i],$r{13}[$i],$r{14}[$i],$r{15}[$i],$r{16}[$i],$r{17}[$i],$r{18}[$i],$r{19}[$i],$r{20}[$i],$r{21}[$i]), ';');
}
fclose($fp) ;
```

How can I avoid having to copy and paste from r{0}[$i] to r{21}[$i] in this example ? I'm sure, the answer is right in front of me, but I've spent too much time on the code before theses lines to think clearly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why isn't simply $r an array which you'll serialize at this point ?

Comment: $r is a dynamic variable which is an array too. But it's ok. I got the answer by @Francois B. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nba ; $i++){

     $array = array();
     for($j=0;$j<22;$j++)
          $array[$j] = $r{$j}[$i];

    fputcsv($fp, $array, ';');
}
fclose($fp) ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It's hard to explain what it does. BUt.. it duplicates .. I'd say.. "by line, not row".. I don't know if it has sens for you but I couldn't find anything else :)

Comment: Oops ! My bad, it works great ! I made a mistake. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```html
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nba ; $i++){
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < 22 ; $j++){
        $arry[] = $r{$j}[$i];
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $arry, ';');
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @francois-b code works great. I made a mistake when I tried it.